# Hidden input is not submitted using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Am trying to submit input field and uploading the file using ajax request. Every thing is working well. Except that hidden input value is not sent $(#job).

```
            $.ajaxFileUpload({
                     url         :'careers-training/apply-job/',
                     secureuri      :false,
                     fileElementId  :'cv',
                     dataType    : 'script',
                     data  :{'job' : $('#job').val(),'name' : $('#name').val(),'email' : $('#email').val(),'mobile' : $('#mobile').val(),'cv' : $('#cv').val()},
                     success  : function (Response, status)
                     {

                        var jsonObject = $.parseJSON(Response);
                        if(jsonObject.length == 0)
                        {
                            $(this).HideLoadingPanel();
                            $(this).ShowSuccessPanel();
                            $("#job-application-box").hide();
                            $("#body").attr('style','min-height:400px;')

                        }else{

                            $(this).HideLoadingPanel();
                            $(this).ShowErrorsBox(jsonObject);

                        }

                     }
                  });
```

and this is the HTML:

```
            <form name="apply-job-form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input name="job" id="job" type="hidden" value="dd" />
                <label class="form-label">Name: </label>
                <input class="form-input" type="text" id="name" name="name" /><br />
                <label class="form-label">Mobile: </label>
                <input class="form-input" type="text" id="mobile" name="mobile" /><br />
                <label class="form-label">Email: </label>
                <input class="form-input" type="text" id="email" name="email" /><br />
                <label class="form-label">CV: </label>
                <input class="file-input" type="file" id="cv" name="cv" />
                <button type="button" id="apply-job-button" name="apply-job-button" class="form-button">Apply now !</button>
            </form>
```

So could you help me please ?

Comment: HTML please ???  check if you have hidden input with id job

Comment: Have you checked that $("#job").val() is empty when sending the ajax call? You could be sending the data and your controller losing it (for example if it's binded to a private field)

Answer (score 0):

I have solve the problem. It is related to selectors , so i gonna to change them. Thanx all